# Google Apps API 403 with Service Account

Tags: go, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-oauth, service-accounts

I've been trying make a query against Google's Admin API to list all users in my Google Apps Organization. I have permissions to make this query in the [web UI example](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) and get results, but it 403's when I try to make the query with a service account.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    directory "google.golang.org/api/admin/directory_v1"
)

func main() {
    serviceAccountJSON, err := ioutil.ReadFile(serviceAccountFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not read service account credentials file, %s => {%s}", serviceAccountFile, err)
    }
    config, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(serviceAccountJSON,
        directory.AdminDirectoryUserScope,
        directory.AdminDirectoryUserReadonlyScope,
    )

    client, err := directory.New(config.Client(context.Background()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not create directory service client => {%s}", err)
    }

    users, err := client.Users.List().ViewType(publicDataView).Domain(domain).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to query all users => {%s}", err)
    }

    for _, u := range users.Users {
        fmt.Println(u.Name.FullName)
    }
}
```

Every time I execute I get a 403. The same query parameters works in the `Try it!` section [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list#try-it) so I'm not sure why it fails.

result: `Failed to query all users => {googleapi: Error 403: Not Authorized to access this resource/api, forbidden}`

Comment: did you give the service account access?

Comment: You should give your service account domain wide delegation https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation . Follow the steps mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: I've now given the Service Account access and am waiting for that to propagate. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Despite adding the service account access I am still receiving the same 403 error for this API call. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is a year old, but I couldnt find anything about this anywhere - but ive just managed to fix it after running into the same error as you.

basically you need to set a delegation user to your config, eg:

```
func main() {
    serviceAccountJSON, err := ioutil.ReadFile(serviceAccountFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not read service account credentials file, %s => {%s}", serviceAccountFile, err)
    }
    config, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(serviceAccountJSON,
        directory.AdminDirectoryUserScope,
        directory.AdminDirectoryUserReadonlyScope,
    )

    // Add me
    config.Subject = "someone@example.com"

    client, err := directory.New(config.Client(context.Background()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not create directory service client => {%s}", err)
    }

    users, err := client.Users.List().ViewType(publicDataView).Domain(domain).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to query all users => {%s}", err)
    }

    for _, u := range users.Users {
        fmt.Println(u.Name.FullName)
    }
}
```

See https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/google/example_test.go#L118

hope this helps someone else!

Comment: The question is some time old again, but I have been searching for a solution for some time as well.
For your proposed solution we keep getting `Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.`

Comment: so it's been a little while since ive worked on this, but that sounds like your service account doesnt have domain-wide delegation enabled?
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

Comment: I was buuilding a Net Core 8 app. I was facing the same problem. After some time I found this answer and it works very well.
For those who are working with net core, just add the User property to your ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer
Something like this

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
{
    Scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user" },
    
    // Add me
    User = "YOUR_DELEGATION_USER@YOURDOMAIN.com"
}.FromCertificate(certificate));

Answer (score 0):

The @Chronojam [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38981127/1285075) saved me hours, however on the newer versions of the Google SDK `directory.New` is deprecated, you should be achieve the same thing replacing the `directory.New(...)` line with this one instead:

```golang
    client, err := directory.NewService(context.Background(), option.WithHTTPClient(config.Client(context.Background())))
```